# How can I access my Windows 10 computer from my Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: remote

I have a PC running windows 10 and a raspberry pi 3. I do a lot of music recording, and I cannot reach my computer from where I am positioned (depending on which instrument I am doing at the time). I would also like to use the raspberry pi touchscreen to edit the fader positions of the tracks. My question is: How can I wirelessly connect the raspberry pi to the computer so that I will be able to remotely access the windows 10 machine from the raspberry pi 3?

Comment: Accessing is one thing, controlling Windows applications from Raspberry Pi with a touchscreen connected to the Pi is orders of magnitude more complex. Most likely undoable.

Comment: Some kind of remote desktop utility maybe. VNC? from Pi to Windows? Never really tried that one.. I have noted and will try and see how easy it is to do it that way round. Touchscreen.. yea.. I suppose if VNC supports mouse redirection then touch screen clicks will also work via this Remote Desktop Protocol

Comment: You're going to have a pretty miserable time of it trying to adjust levels like that. I tinkered with teamviewer and android gizmos for a while for the same task, but the latency and small screens is a killer. You might want to consider using an arduino or ESP8266 to build something with physical controls (rotary encoders/flying faders) that talk over midi and identify as a USB device, then looking into using the pi as a wireless USB transmitter.

Comment: @goobering Good idea, I'll try that.

Comment: Note that to RDP into Windows it must be at Professional Edition, it won't work on Home.

Answer (score 1):

If you need access remotely to MS Windows, you can use Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP). There are many application that implement it.

For example this one.
https://www.weaved.com/weaved-with-windows-remote-desktop-rdp-raspberry-pi/